# Skrollr.js using document as anchor-target regardless of which anchor-target is specified

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using relative positioned `<section>`s to attach Skrollr events in relative mode. However, the Skrollr events are always firing as if the document top is the anchor point. I have set `data-anchor-target` for various sections to test, but always it is treating document top as the anchor point.

I am using Skrollr-stylesheets but I've tried using straight Skrollr and the problem is identical, therefore I can rule out stylesheets as a cause.

Are there any situations which may cause this issue?

Here's some key pieces of code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
    <section id="section1" class="section section1">
        <div class="wrap">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section2" class="section section2">
        <div class="wrap">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section3" class="section section3">
        <div class="wrap">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**style.scss**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#skrollr-body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

**skrollr.css**

```
#section2 {
    -skrollr-animation-name:animation1;
}

@-skrollr-keyframes animation1 {
    200-top {
        border: 5px solid red;
    }
}

@-skrollr-keyframes animation1 {
    -200-bottom {
        border: 5px solid blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce what you're saying. If I copy your code, nothing is animating at all. That's because you have defined `animation1` two times. Use this instead:

```
@-skrollr-keyframes animation1 {
    200-top {
        border: 5px solid red;
    }

    -200-bottom {
        border: 5px solid blue;
    }
}
```